# How to read a list and create a dictionary with the data?

Tags: python

The problem I have to do is to write a program that reads the contents of a text file and creates a dictionary in which the keys are individual unique words and the value is a list that contains the line numbers in the file where the word is found. [The following problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kp7F.png) I have so far figured out how to read the text file but have no idea how to transfer that data onto the dictionary. Hope someone can help thanks!

```
with open('Kennedy.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n').lower() for line in open('Kennedy.txt')]
    lines.pop()
    print(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list) # initialize a dict with values as lists

with open('Kennedy.txt') as fin:
    for idx, line in enumerate(fin): # for index, line in file
        words = line.lower().split() # make it case insensitive
        for word in words: # for word in list of lower-case words
            d[word].append(idx) # append the value to the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` to produce the line numbers, and append them to lists of the dict indexed by the words.

```
output = {}
with open('Kennedy.txt') as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f.readlines(), 1):
        for w in l.lower().split():
            output.setdefault(w, []).append[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    words_dict = dict()

    with open('Kennedy.txt', 'r') as f:
        i = 0
        for line in f:
            i += 1
            for word in line.strip().split(' '):
                word = word.lower()
                if word not in words_dict.keys():
                    words_dict[word] = []
                words_dict[word].append(i)

    print(words_dict)
```